# FFmpegMediaPlayer Stops When Network is Turned Off and Back On

Tags: android, ffmpeg, android-mediaplayer

I am currently working with FFmpegMediaPlayer in order to make a basic music player given a url. I got the basic functionality to work. On error, I show an error message, else I play the songs. 
The problem I am facing is, once the player starts, and I turn off my wifi and phone data, it stops the sound. Once I turn my wifi or phone data back one, I would like the player to continue but it simply stops. I have to stop and play again for it to continue.

Is there a way to have the FFmpegMediaPlayer continue streaming?

This is what I have to initialize the player:

```
mMediaPlayer = new FFmpegMediaPlayer();
    mMediaPlayer.setOnErrorListener(this);
    mMediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(this);
    mMediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
    mMediaPlayer.setOnBufferingUpdateListener(this);
    mMediaPlayer.setOnSeekCompleteListener(this);

    try {
        Uri uri = Uri.parse(radio_url);
        mMediaPlayer.setDataSource(mMainActivity, uri);
        mMediaPlayer.prepareAsync();
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (SecurityException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Then I have a function to handle when Play/Stop button is clicked:

```
@Override
public void onPlayButtonClicked(Button button) {

    if (radioInitialized) {
        mAnalytics.onStopButtonClicked();
        mMainLayout.loading(false);
        mMediaPlayer.pause();
     button.setBackground(mMainActivity.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.play_button));
        radioInitialized = false;
    } else {
        mAnalytics.onPlayButtonClicked();
        mMainLayout.loading(true);
        initRadio();
        button.setBackground(mMainActivity.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.stop_button));
        radioInitialized = true;
    }
}
```

Again, the basic functionality works, but I would like for it to continue streaming after wifi is turned back on.

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution.

My main goal was to create a media player like a radio.

I tried MediaPlayer and it works but it tends to stop frequently.

I then tried vitamio and FFmpegMediaPlayer. Vitamio was confusing and FFmpegMediaPlayer doesn't support on streaming error.

I currently got it working with Google's Exo Player. There is a very nice tutorial here: https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/exoplayer-intro/index.html?index=..%2F..%2Findex#0